# How to fit image with col-sm-12 in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

So there two columns , i wanna fit my image inside my first column so my second column can go down!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTSHw.jpg)

my HTML :

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="hero-image container-fluid">
                    <img class="man-with-laptop img-fluid"
                        src="https://demo.templateflip.com/super/images/illustrations/hello3.svg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="hero-text-area container-fluid">
                    <p>HELLO!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please don't tag this with multiple different major bootstrap versions at the same time, that is not helpful. Tag with the version you are actually using.

Comment: And what you actually want to know here now, is hard to understand. Please clarify what the issue is. Ideally with a proper, verbal explanation, and not just by holding up pictures.

Comment: Could you expand on what 'my second column can go down' means? It sounds as though you want it not to be a column but to fill the second row - but I can't be sure.

Comment: I am struggling with a poor description of the problem too. Do you mean that all of that Hello Text and your red highlights are supposed to be positioned below the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this below and see what  happens.... 1 container, 1 row.

Also, it looks like you're adding a lot of your own CSS I can see from your `class` types. I think your added CSS is messing about with your layout and confusing Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
             <img class="man-with-laptop img-fluid" src="https://demo.templateflip.com/super/images/illustrations/hello3.svg" alt="">
         </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
           <p>HELLO!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```